# Add additional option on all automounts brought in from +auto.master

Tags: automount, autofs

I am looking for a way to enable `cachefilesd` across all automounts that we inherit via `+master.conf`.  To do this, I need to be able to add `-o fsc` to the mount options.

Is there a way to override the NFS options in the maps to add an additional option?

I found `add_options` for auto.conf, but I think that is about autofs options, not mount options.

Answer (score 0):

`add_options` is indeed part of the secret.  At least on CentOS 7, you can add `OPTIONS="-O fsc"` to `/etc/sysconfig/autofs`.

If `add_options` is true, then `-O` will add (instead of replace) the options with `fsc`.